# MySql Avg runtime data to limit number of rows

Tags: mysql

I am using a tool that can not render(generate the graphs) the information if it contains more that 1000 data points, so suppose if my mysql query returning around 5000 data points then I have to convert this 5000 data points into 1000 points by taking average of all the values. This conversion rate 5000/1000 = 5, I have to decide at runtime. Is there any way I can group/average the data based on datasize and column name rather then just a column name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you reduce/average the set of rows? Theoretically, you could number each row, then wrap that query in something like `SELECT AVG(data) FROM ( ... ) GROUP BY rownum % 1000` to guarantee the number of results returned would never exceed 1000. This would average row 1 with rows 1001, 2001, 3001, 4001, and 5001... but does that make sense? Probably not.

Comment: Or you could create a procedure which iterates through your 5000 rows in groups of 5, and average between 1-5, 6-10, 11-15 and so on.

Comment: I need to iterate over 5000 times then in first case I need to store all this dynamic query into some batch/curson/variable(I donot know which One is possible) then execute all this query and club the results or In second case I will execute each query and handle the results into cursor and then club the final results...but unfortunatly I am new to mysql and have no idea about both way. query I am using "Select id, avg(scenarioElapsedTimeInSec),avg(vuserCount) from( Select * from summaryvuserresult where resultid = 1210 limit 5) datatable group by scenarioElapsedTimeInSec"

Answer (score 0):

**Sorting using auto-increment field**

What user113215 said (`SELECT AVG(data) FROM ... GROUP BY rownum % 1000`) makes sense, except that if there's 5050 rows there would be 50 rows that are the average of 6 rows each, while the other 950 will be the average of 5 rows each. How do you want to handle this case? Split them evenly across 5050/6 rows instead? If so, I suggest you run 2 queries, the first is just something like:

```
SELECT SUM(*)/(CEIL(SUM(*))/1000) FROM YourTable
```

the output of which you store in a variable to use to mod with in the next query.

An alternative to `% 1000` is just `/ 5`, so that you can average sequential rows instead.

You should generally have an auto-increment primary key for a table, which would make this solution simple enough.

**Custom sorting**

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651688/get-the-average-of-groups-of-n-rows-with-mysql) is exactly what you want.